# Match one or more 0 symbols before the end off the string with regular expression

Tags: regex, pcre

Let's assume we have some strings which look like this: `ABCDEFGH000000` (quantity of zeroes in the end may vary). We need to match this "0" symbols before the end of the line with regexps.

When I write something like `/(^.*)(0+$)/` I match only last "0" symbol. But if I write something like this `/^(.*)(0{6,})/` I match my six zeros. The problem is -- I can have more than 6 zeroes (or less than 6), so `{6,}` can't be used.

How do I match all the coherent "0" symbols before the end of the string propely? I use PCRE

UPD I have to capture matched results (zeroes and non zeroes)

Comment: You didn't mention if you actually needed to capture anything. Assuming you don't, your pattern would just be `0+$`

Comment: I actually have to capture both results, thats why I used ()

Comment: If quantity of zeroes may vary, maybe its best to also use the `*` multiplier on top of Barmar's answer? Otherwise you might end up with no match at all.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `*` is greedy, so `.*` matches the longest possible string that still allows the rest of the regexp to match. Since `0+` succeeds with just a single `0`, `.*` can match everything before that, including all the other `0` characters.

Use a non-greedy quantifier to match the part before `0`:

```
/(^.*?)(0+$)/
```

Answer (score 1):

`/0+$/`

Regexp try to make the longest match so in your first case the .* eats all the zeros except the last needed one.

Comment: Won't capture both parts as later specified.  @Barmar has it right for that case!

Answer (score 0):

To save the possibly time-consuming lazy regex, the regex match/capture can be simplified to (0+)$ and $`$1, respectively. Where supported, $` captures the string before the match.